# check TFTP share

Tags: linux, share, tftp

is there any way to check which folders are shared by TFTP ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the daemon runs with the shared directory as an argument, try

```
ps auxww | grep tftpd
```

if it's running as a detached process, or

```
less /etc/xinetd.d/*tftp*
```

if it's running under xinetd.  You're looking for something like `in.tftpd /tftpboot`, which would indicate that `/tftpboot` was the shared directory.

If it's got no argument it'll be using the compiled-in defaults, in that case check the man page or run `strings` on the binary and take a shrewd guess.  If you do the latter, do check the guess by putting a file with a random name in that directory, and try retrieving it with tftp.